# Use query string variable to disable shiny widget on page load?

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

Here's what I'd like to do in an Rmarkdown document with `runtime: shiny` -

- Read the query string
- Get a default argument for a textInput from variable in query string
- Disable the textInput if variable in query string indicates

The problem seems to be that reading the query string must be done in a reactive context, but building the interface happens outside a reactive context. This is my first attempt, as an Rmarkdown file:

````
---
title: "Test session variables"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: row
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
require(flexdashboard)
require(shinyjs)
useShinyjs(rmd=TRUE)
```

```{r}

observe({
  query = getQueryString()
  ID = query[['ID']]
  active = query[['IDactive']]

  if (!is.null(ID)) {
    updateTextInput(session, 'ID', value = ID)
  }
  if(!is.null(active)){
    if(active == '0'){
      disable('ID')
    }
  }
})

```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
textInput("ID", label = "ID:", width = "150px", placeholder = "ID", value = "hi")
```

Row  {data-height=60}
------------------------------------

### Other 

Row 
-------------------------------------

### Query string

```{r}
renderUI({
    query <- getQueryString()
    return(HTML(jsonlite::toJSON(query)))
})
```
````

When I run this and add the appropriate variables in the query string, the textInput gets updated, but not disabled. Dean Attali (the author of shinyjs) has [told me](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/147#issuecomment-347930659) this is due to the fact that the textInput does not exist yet when the `disable` is run.

My question is: how can I use a variable in the query string to disable a widget when the Rmarkdown page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All UI is rendered dynamically in `runtime: shiny` documents, so the observer would indeed run before either the text input or `shinyjs` load. So even though the `textInput` looks static, it's actually being rendered in the document through a `renderUI`/`uiOutput`.

You'll either have to get the observer to run after the dynamic UI has rendered, or use a prerendered Shiny document (`runtime: shiny_prerendered`) for static UI. Here's an example of each:

#### Delay observer execution until dynamic UI has rendered

````
---
title: "Test session variables"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: row
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
require(flexdashboard)
require(shinyjs)
useShinyjs(rmd=TRUE)
```

```{r}
observeEvent(input$ID, {
  observe({
    query = getQueryString()
    ID = query[['ID']]
    active = query[['IDactive']]

    if (!is.null(ID)) {
      updateTextInput(session, 'ID', value = ID)
    }

    if (!is.null(active)) {
      if (active == '0') {
        disable('ID')
      }
    }
  })
}, once = TRUE)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
textInput("ID", label = "ID:", width = "150px", placeholder = "ID", value = "hi")
```

Row  {data-height=60}
------------------------------------

### Other 

Row 
-------------------------------------

### Query string

```{r}
renderUI({
  query <- getQueryString()
  return(HTML(jsonlite::toJSON(query)))
})
```
````

#### Prerendered Shiny document

````
---
title: "Test session variables"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: row
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r}
require(flexdashboard)
require(shinyjs)
useShinyjs(rmd=TRUE)
```

```{r, context="server"}
observe({
  query = getQueryString()
  ID = query[['ID']]
  active = query[['IDactive']]

  if (!is.null(ID)) {
    updateTextInput(session, 'ID', value = ID)
  }

  if (!is.null(active)) {
    if (active == '0') {
      disable('ID')
    }
  }
})

output$query <- renderUI({
  query <- getQueryString()
  return(HTML(jsonlite::toJSON(query)))
})
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
textInput("ID", label = "ID:", width = "150px", placeholder = "ID", value = "hi")
```

Row  {data-height=60}
------------------------------------

### Other 

Row 
-------------------------------------

### Query string

```{r}
uiOutput("query")
```
````

---

#### Dynamically rendered UI

Just another option - you could also dynamically render the `textInput` based on the query string. I used `shinyjs::disabled` here to disable the text input.

````
---
title: "Test session variables"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: row
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
require(flexdashboard)
require(shinyjs)
useShinyjs(rmd=TRUE)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
renderUI({
  query <- getQueryString()
  value <- if (!is.null(query[['ID']])) query[['ID']] else "hi"
  disabled <- identical(query[['IDactive']], "0")

  idInput <- textInput("ID", label = "ID:", width = "150px", placeholder = "ID", value = value)

  if (disabled) {
    shinyjs::disabled(idInput)
  } else {
    idInput
  }
})
```

Row  {data-height=60}
------------------------------------

### Other 

Row 
-------------------------------------

### Query string

```{r}
renderUI({
  query <- getQueryString()
  return(HTML(jsonlite::toJSON(query)))
})
```
````